# Unable to use Custom control in Windows 8 Metro Apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to consume Custom Control in Windows 8 Metro Apps. It's working fine if I'm refering my custom control in other project within **same solution** but unable to successfully add reference of control to a different project in **different solution**.

Everytime I add reference to the control extension in my project, I always get this error "Insufficient memory to continue the program"

I've taken the  help from this link but its not working on Windows 8 Release preview:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx

Windows 8 Release Preview
Visual studio 2012 beta